# Can't execute wineserver

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install Wine 2.0.2, I compiled it, I installed it, I've done everything but when I try to do `winecfg` or `wineboot` i get this error : `wine: could not exec wineserver`

What can I do?

Comment: What happens if you execute `wineserver`?

Comment: @Hi-Angel tells me to install wine1.6 via apt-get

Comment: Odd. Ok, I think it's pretty tedious to determine what went wrong in comments, but to give you some directions: the package you built should have `wineserver` executable. So, check if it was built, list the files of the package you made *(I hope [you didn't use `make install`, did you?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264211/why-do-people-say-make-install-is-bad))*, perhaps was `wineserver` installed into some weird place instead of `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel i did use make install

Comment: @Hi-Angel what I'm trying to do is installing World of Tanks beacuse PlayOnLinux is just an arsehole with me

Comment: Ok, it's just not a very good practice. To give you an example: right now you can't list the files you installed to determine whether you have had `wineserver` or not because you didn't make package. You just unpacked the built files into your filesystem.

Comment: @Hi-Angel alright, so how do I delete everything and installing it properly with some patches

Comment: @Hi-Angel if you check my profile I asked some days ago how to apply a patch on Wine, beacuse it's a raw input patch

Comment: Usually `make install` have `make uninstall` counterpart, you can try it. But it is not at all critical, you need to find what's up with `wineserver`. Btw, out off top of my head, `make install` could have installed into some prefix, like `/usr/local/bin/`, or something alike *(don't remember the dir name)*. You might try adding `--prefix=/usr` to `configure` command line. But it's a lot of time to compile, so you better check this assumption beforehand.

Comment: @Hi-Angel no worries about waiting

Comment: @Hi-Angel i will reinstall it, I might deleted all wine things from `/usr/bin` beacusr it was from another version

Comment: You don't actually want to deal with building/installing idiosyncrasies, you just wanna play World Of Tanks, don't you? Then perhaps is it worth to just install wine [from their official PPA](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)?

Comment: @Hi-Angel yes but there is a raw input mouse patch that i gotta install, do you have any idea how to keep the mouse inside the wine window and not get out from it?

Comment: Try setting *`winecfg` → Graphics → ✓Emulate a virtual desktop* and *✓Automatically capture the mouse in full-screen windows* in the same tab.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thank you very much, It's working on WoT, BF2, SWAT 4